# How to use the CorsHttpHandler with handler.yml in light-4j application

Tags: cors, light-4j

I am running through the CORS tutorial here to add CORS into our project: https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/middleware/cors/
and I think I am missing a step or something to review what I've tried:

added the cors.yml file to src/main/resources/config
included the dependency in pom.xml

added the MiddlewareHandler and the CorsHttpHandler to service.yml

I was still getting CORS blocking requests, so since our project uses handler.yml, I instead reverted that third change and instead added the CorsHttpHandler to handler.yml, directly after the CorrelationHandler
that also didn't work though it seems like that third step is the one that I am missing: what change should I be making to handler.yml to enable CORS?

the other things I've also tried are using com.networknt.cors.PathHandlerProvider instead of com.networknt.cors.CorsHttpHandler and changing its order in the handler/service ymls.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define the handler chain. In the old method in service.yml, you can only define one handler chain per application. For big applications, there are numeric endpoints and sometimes, you have REST and GraphQL in the same application with totally different middleware handlers per endpoint. So we have added another way to define the handler chain(s) in handler.yml. For new applications, it is highly recommended using handler.yml and the new version of light-codegen will generate it from the specification. The [CORS tutorial](https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/middleware/cors/) is just updated to leverage the handler.yml and the [cors example application](https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j/tree/master/rest/openapi/cors) has been redone. Thanks for raising the issue.